# Iterate over folders and move files up one level

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
/images
  /1
    /.tmp
      image1.jpg
      image2.jpg
  /2
    .tmp
      image1.jpg
      image2.jpg
      image3.jpg
  /3
    .tmp
      image1.jpg
      image2.jpg
```

What I need is to move all of those files in .tmp up one level, so their paths are `images/1/image1.jpg` rather than `images/1/.tmp/image1.jpg`. The issue is that I have hundreds or thousands of these numbered folders, so doing it by hand would take forever.

Is there an OS X or Unix shell command that I could iterate over each /.tmp  folder and move the contents up a level, or something like:

```
mv images/*/.tmp/* images/< the current dir being iterated over>/*
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `find` supports the `-execdir` command (which [OSX's `find` apparently does](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html)), then you could do:

```
find . -iname '*.jpg' -execdir mv {} .. \;
```

`-execdir` runs the command from the directory where the file was found, so `..` will refer to that file's directory's parent directory.

You can refine this to force matching a `.tmp` directory:

```
find . -path '*/.tmp/*.jpg' -execdir mv {} .. \;
```

However, `*` in `-path` also matches `/`, so this will also match, for example, `images/.tmp/foo/image.jpg`.

You could do:

```
find . -type d -name .tmp -print0 | xargs -0I_ find _ -maxdepth 1 -name '*.jpg' -execdir mv {} .. \;
```

Or, using `find`'s regex support:

```
find . -regex '.*/\.tmp/[^/]*\.jpg' -execdir mv {} .. \;
```

Comment: Yep just realised! I thought it just took the file/path as though it was.

Comment: The only concern here is that if there are ALSO `*.jpg` files in directories that are NOT `.tmp`, you'll move them to other places as well. Can you adjust this so it only affects files located in `.tmp` directories?

Comment: @muru You can use regex instead of path or the pipe.

Comment: @123 hmm, yes `-regex '.*/\.tmp/[^/]*\.jpg'` should be enough. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

From scratch without testing:

```
cd /images
for i in $(find ./ -name *.jpg)
do
d = $(dirname $i)
d = $(dirname $d)
echo $i $d
# test! before use the next
# mv $i $d
done
```

Comment: Never do this: `for x in $(command)` or ``command`` or `$var`. for-in is used for iterating arguments, not (output) strings. Instead, use a glob (eg. *.txt), arrays (eg. `"${names[@]}"`) or a while-read 
                loop (eg. `while read -r line`). See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#pf1 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: With `find`, the way to use read would be `find … -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' -r i; do …`